# How to un-shorten t.co links with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I've got a twitter plugin that prints **t.co** links. How can I 'un-short' them with jQuery? Is there a library I could use?

I did some searches but I can't find anything. Maybe I'm searching on the wrong thing...

Comment: Crap.. I marked the wrong question as "duplicate". Sorry.

Comment: @Plynx Did you really reference a possible duplicate AS a possible duplicate?

Comment: @Ian it wasn't marked as a duplicate until 9 minutes ago, so no. At the least, we can all consolidate the questions on the one with the most helpful answers.

Comment: @Plynx Jeez I'm dumb. I saw the date on the actual question, and didn't bother to look at the hidden comment that showed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/duotrigesimal/XB8Uf/

It makes a request to the api at LongURL (http://longurl.org/api#expand-url) to get the expanded url.

```
var tests = [
    'http://t.co/NJwI2ugt', 
    'http://www.google.com' //nothing should happen
];

var expander = {
    expand: function (url, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand',
            data: {
                url: url,
                format: 'json'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                callback(response);
            }
        });
    }
};

for(i in tests) {

    expander.expand( tests[i], function(response) {
        $('#output').append(response['long-url']+'<br>');
        console.dir(response);
    });

}
```

Comment: wonderful... just wrapped it in a small object an it is really good to go!

Comment: It appears that the site http://longurl.org is no longer online.